# Formatting phone number in Slack message?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, slack

Is there a way to format a phone number returned in a Slack message as a clickable link which opens the phone icon? I have a chatbot which integrates with Slack and sends messages to a channel. One of those messages has a phone number which appears as just text and does not get highlighted as clickable.

I know a lot of apps do this, like email, sms, etc. so I was hoping Slack would automatically detect a phone number. I'm specifically using the Android Slack app.

Any help would be appreciated!

### EDIT:

Figured it out, had to add '-' to the phone number for Slack to automatically pick up the phone number. So something like 604-445-5566 would be picked up but 6044555566 would not be picked up as a phone number!

Comment: can you add your EDIT as the answer so that I can mark it as upvote?

Comment: @VarunChandak done!

Answer (score 6):

when you send the message send it this format "<tel:00000|00000>" and it will be clickable with the option to call that number

Answer (score 3):

For me only adding '+' before the number making it clickable. 
Windows and iOS clients.

Comment: This worked for me. Another answer said to use `<tel:00000|00000>` but that didn’t work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the Slack bot development, but I believe you can make it to a clickable link just like a hyperlink, but the link target is `tel:1-408-555-5555`. When clicked, browsers are smart enough to redirect the user to the native phone call function.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, sending as a link would not work with Slack because it needs to 'unfurl' the link and I have multiple phone numbers in a single message. Solution was actually really simple...had to add dashes between the numbers and it automatically picks it up!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, had to add '-' to the phone number for Slack to automatically pick up the phone number. So something like 604-445-5566 would be picked up but 6044555566 would not be picked up as a phone number!